# scalaz: how to handle different error types in a Validation?

Tags: scala, validation, scalaz

If I have multiple operations that return a `Validation[E, _]` of something with a fixed error type I can use them in a for-comprehension. For example:

```
val things: Validation[E, (Int, Double)] = for {
  i <- getValidationOfInt
  d <- getValidationOfDouble
} yield (i, d)
```

What about if the error types are different? Suppose I read from HTTP and want to convert the string response into an `Int`.

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._

object ValidationMixing {
  class HttpError

  def getFromHttp: Validation[HttpError, String] = ???
  def parseInt(json: String): Validation[Throwable, Int] =
    Validation.fromTryCatchNonFatal(Integer.parseInt(json))

  val intParsedFromHttp: Validation[Any, Int] = for {
    s <- getFromHttp
    i <- parseInt(s)
  } yield i
}
```

This compiles, but only because the error type of the Validation is `Any`, being a supertype of `Throwable` and `HttpError`. This isn't very helpful.

I can think of various ways of representing such a combined error type that are more useful than `Any` (e.g. `Validation[Error1 \/ Error2, Result]` to store either, `Validation[String, Result]` translating to an error message, etc) but they all have drawbacks.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Not really what you want but the way I solved this was having a generic `Error` trait and have subclasses for it, then you could do `fromTryCatchNonFatal(...).leftMap(t => MyError(...))` where `MyError` is a subtype of the generic `Error`, for two reason, the first is the one you highlighted in your question, the second is to have an error that is meaningful to me/app instead of a throwable, also you have more context where the error is generated which helps generating a meaningful error.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the consensus: if there's no error hierarchy, make one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has had a better idea I'll leave my answer for future reference.

As said in the comment the best way is to create a error hierarchy:

```
trait GenericError {  /* some commond fields */}
case class MyNumericError(/* fields */)
```

and then use `leftMap` on a validation to generate appropriate errors:

```
Validation.fromTryCatchNonFatal(...).leftMap(t => MyNumericError(...))
```

This approach has two advantages

- First you will always have a `Validation[GenericError, T]` so not having different types on the left part of that validation
- The second is that this helps generate meaningful errors for both developers and service user, also note that generating an error where you have many context informations helps in this process.